# How can I allow my try block to work multiple times?

Tags: try-catch

So I've been trying to do a loop when working with classes but I find that fixing errors work once. Here's my code:

```
class team:
    def __init__(self,budget):
        self.budget = budget      

def test_func():
    team.budget = input("How much money should your baseball team own? ")
    try:
        team.budget = int(team.budget)
    except ValueError:
        print("Either you added a dollar sign, put in text or tried something weird. Either way, don't do that.")
        team.budget = input("How much money should your baseball team own? ")

test_func()
```

This try block should block anything that's not an integer, but here's what happens when I cause an error twice:

[image: After adding user input.]

Is there something you'd recommend to allow the input to happen until the user enters in something acceptable?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop to repeat the prompt until a valid integer is entered.

```py
def test_func():
    while True:
        team.budget = input("How much money should your baseball team own? ")
        try:
            team.budget = int(team.budget)

            break  # Stop the loop since the input is valid.
        except ValueError:
            print("Either you added a dollar sign, put in text or tried something weird. Either way, don't do that.")
```

Comment: I wish I thought of that. I should have. Thanks!